# Find a divergent sequence whose distance lessens with each subsequent term

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, cauchy-sequences

The question states

Give an example of a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_{n+1} − a_n| = 0$ but which is divergent.

I'm slamming my head against a table thinking of all the divergent sequences I know, but any oscillating sequences like $(-1)^n$ don't work when taking the distances between subsequent values.

I tried thinking of divergent Cauchy sequences but none seem to apply to this problem.

Any suggestions for sequences to try?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but wouldn't the sequence of rationals approaching $\sqrt{2}$ with the usual metric in $\mathbb{Q}$ achieve your result? Or would the partial sums of the harmonic series work?

Comment: would it hold as n goes to infinity though? beyond square root of 2?

Comment: Do you know a divergent series whose terms converge to zero? By definition the partial sums of such a series fulfill your criteria.

Comment: The harmonic series is one example. $\left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n} \right) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ but the partial sums do not converge.

Comment: @JessSavoie I posted an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a_n$ be the $n$-th partial sum of the harmonic series. Then $a_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\dfrac{1}{i}$ and the difference between successive terms $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ is $\dfrac{1}{n+1}$, which clearly goes to $0$, but the harmonic series is known to be divergent.

A second example. Consider the metric space $(\mathbb{Q},d)$, where $d$ is the usual metric. The sequence $1, 1.4, 1.41, 1.414,...$ approaching $\sqrt{2}$ is clearly Cauchy but does not converge, since $\sqrt{2}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 2):

A trick for generating such examples is to find a sequence that goes to infinity, but it does it very slowly. One example where the sequence grows slowly is to take $a_n = \sqrt{n}$. For,
$$
\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = \frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\cdot\big(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\big) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} \to 0,
$$
but $\sqrt n \to \infty$.

For an even slower sequence, take a look at $a_n = \log n$. Then $\log n\to\infty$, yet
$$
\log(n+1)-\log(n) = \log\bigg(\frac{n+1}{n}\bigg) \to \log(1) = 0.
$$
This example uses the identity $\log(a)-\log(b) = \log(a/b)$, the continuity of $\log$ and the fact that $\frac{n+1}{n}\to 1$.

Comment: I really like the $\log$ example.